# Applescript right click a file

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there a command in apple script to right click a file and bring up the context menu?

I'm looking for something like

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theDesktopItems to every item of desktop
    right click item 1 of theDesktopItems
end tell
```

Comment: Which item do you want to choose from the popup menu? There might be a way to do it directly, without menu.

Comment: I just need to show the menu. Then the user will select the item manually.

Comment: @James Wondering if this worked out for you? If so it would be good to mark the question answered or share your result.

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for the System Events application. It can be used to reach menu items and their actions in most applications, even those that are otherwise not scriptable.

Try this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set target_index to 1
        set target to image target_index of group 1 of scroll area 1
        tell target to perform action "AXShowMenu"
    end tell
end tell
```

Check this link for an overview of using System Events if you are so inclined: http://n8henrie.com/2013/03/a-strategy-for-ui-scripting-in-applescript/

Comment: Cool tip. I didn't know action "AXShowMenu" would show the right-click menu.

Comment: Hi adamh, Can you elaborate on the details of using the script? I tried adding this script in automator and assigned a shortcut in system preference, but when I press the shortcut it doesn't do anything. I can mind create a new question so that you get more credit for answering this in details. Thanks.

Comment: @VicJang yeah could be an automator issue, best to start a new question, be sure to mention what os version you are on too. cheers

Comment: @adamh I have started a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226133/show-context-menu-on-mac-with-keyboard-using-applescript-and-automator) Thank you!

Comment: Hi @adamh just a reminder that I have posted a new question. Please help me answer it (if you have an answer and willing to share of course) if you can. Thank you!