# Show context menu on Mac with keyboard using AppleScript and Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, contextmenu, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to find a way to bring up the context menu in Finder on a Mac with Yosemite **without** touching the mouse/touchpad.

[image: a context menu]
*A context menu.*

After extensive research on this issue, the only possible route seems to be using AppleScript with Automator, and assign keyboard shortcut to it.

The AppleScript below was found on stackoverflow, if I run it inside the Automator, it would bring up the context menu on one of the files on the desktop (not the file currently selected.)

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set target_index to 1
        set target to image target_index of group 1 of scroll area 1
        tell target to perform action "AXShowMenu"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

[image]
*Automator screenshot*

But I am having trouble getting it to work with keyboard shortcut.
Also I will need to make sure that it brings the menu for the currently selected file.

Can someone provide some insight about how this can be done?

Comment: I don't know the answer for certain, but I wonder if you need to enable Automator or AppleScript to be able to use the Accessibility API's.  [Here's an Apple support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202802) that talks about this a little bit.

Comment: The accessibility thing popped up the first time I try to run the script, and I have since added Automator (and Scrip Editor) to the list. So that's probably not it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the script below here: [MacScripter / right click](http://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=178866#p178866)

```
 # Copyright © 2012 - 2015 McUsr
 run showRightClickMenu
 script showRightClickMenu
    on run
        set mouseLoc to (do shell script "~/opt/bin/MouseTools -location")
        set {astid, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}
        tell mouseLoc to set {mouseX, mouseY} to {it's text item 1, it's text item 2}
        set {mouseX, mouseY} to {(mouseX as integer), 1200 - (mouseY as integer)}

        tell application id "sevs"
            set frontProcessName to name of every process whose frontmost is true
            --    tell a to set aa to (get its name)
            set wnCount to count of windows of process named frontProcessName
            if wnCount > 0 then
                tell window 1 of process named frontProcessName
                    set wnPos to its position
                    set wnsize to its size
                end tell
                set {wnX, wnY, wnWidth, wnHeight} to {item 1 of wnPos, item 2 of wnPos, item 1 of wnsize, item 2 of wnsize}

                set {leftBound, RightBound, upperBound, lowerBound} to {wnX + 1, (wnX + wnWidth - 21), wnY + 50, (wnY + wnHeight - 51)}
                if mouseX ≥ leftBound and mouseX ≤ RightBound then
                else if mouseX < leftBound then
                    set mouseX to leftBound
                else
                    set mouseX to RightBound
                end if

                if mouseY ≥ upperBound and mouseY ≤ lowerBound then
                else if mouseY < upperBound then
                    set mouseY to upperBound
                else
                    set mouseY to lowerBound
                end if

            end if
        end tell
        set mouseLoc to "c" & mouseX & " " & mouseY
        do shell script "~/opt/bin/cliclick " & mouseLoc
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to astid
    end run
 end script
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not what I was expecting, but if this script gets the job done, I might as well just use it. I'll try it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

This will bring up the context menu of the currently selected file of the desktop:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sel to get the selection

    if (sel is {}) then
        log "Nothing selected! Can't proceed"
        return
    end if

    set target_item_name to the name of (item 1 of sel) 
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        tell group 1 of scroll area 1
            set target to the first image whose value of attribute "AXFilename" is target_item_name
            tell target to perform action "AXShowMenu"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

**Tested on 10.8.5 in script editor*

Comment: It does work for Desktop item when tested in script editor! But when I try with item in the Finder (any folder other than Desktop), it gives me this error: http://i.imgur.com/WsJddmj.png Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I played around with it a bit, and it seems that the script is trying to get the index with the current filename "in Desktop". It's looking in the wrong place, that's how the error occurred.  I guess I need to change something about the group and scroll area?

Comment: @VicJang Yes desktop only, targeting specific window should be possible, dealing with all possible permutations of the view(icon, column, list etc) could get complex. Might be best to stick to list view as in your screen shot, if i get a chance this week i'll have a look. Otherwise you could start looking into trying to find out how to reference the window of the selected item with System Events.  (i.e, as apposed to the desktop; group1 of scroll area 1)