# How to right click screen coordinate with mouse from command line on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, unix

Is there a built command line utility to right click a screen coordinate on  OSX?

Is it possible to do so with a secondary cursory such that the main cursor is not re-positioned on the screen?

Comment: Do you mean to send a right click to another application from Bash? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350448/applescript-right-click-a-file). Code like that can be sent from Bash with `osascript`

Answer (score 0):

If you type the key combo of command-shift-4 the curser is turned into crosshairs and the cursor position is listed on the cusor itself. Shown below is a screen capture of an area of screen containing the cross-hairs.

[image: Cross-Hairs]